# microsoft fluent UI library doesn't work with react 18

Tags: reactjs, fluent-ui

[microsoft fluent-UI/react](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui) library did not work on my project when I included it, what is the best way to make this work properly? the UI broke immediately after I ran the project and I would like to know what the best fix is to this problem

Comment: Can you please share your code so that we can advise you better?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no proper fix for this yet. And it looks like dev team is not considering this issue as high priority. Check out this [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/22241).

Comment: Format needs to be improved and you can use hyperlink markdown to share links instead of pasting directly.

Answer (score 0):

Pls use following command and following library  **Fluent UI - React Northstar** able to work with react v18

```
npm i @fluentui/react-northstar --legacy-peer-deps
```